# How to avoid closing Activity when going to previous fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity which consists of 2 fragments, what I have put down in my activity backpressed is something like this..

```
private Boolean exit = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);    
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
}
```

this  leads directly to close the app even if i am at fragment 2, actually what should happen is it should go back to fragment 1 not closed any help...

Comment: can you post your code going from Fragment1 to fragment2

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int fragmentCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (fragmentCount == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        if (fragmentCount > 1) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

see if it works or not. By the way its not my work but it should work.

Comment: what is that drawerLayout??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check are you adding your fragment to `stack` or not. For example if you want to navigate from `FirstFragment` to `SecondFragment`,

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
transaction.commit();
```

Then in your `activity` override `onBackPressed` as,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
     } else {
          super.onBackPressed();
     }
}
```

Above method navigate from `FirstFragment` to `SecondFragment`, on click of back button on `SecondFragment` (and if fragment stack is empty, it back from activity on back button pressed).

**Edit: -** And always try to start a fragment from activity. Never from fragment(it's not a good practice). Because fragment is basically a instance of activity, so it need to start from a activity context to perform better instead of fragment context.

For example if you want to start `SecondFragment` from `FirstFragment` then in your activity create a method as,

```
public void startSecondFragment(){
   FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
   FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
   transaction.commit();
}
```

Then in your `FirstFragment` when you want to start `SecondFragment` you can start as,

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).startSecondFragment();
```

Comment: really helpful material thank you so much @Heisen-Berg

Comment: Approve it, if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **addToBackStack(null)** on fragment transaction like that.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, list)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

On activity `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.